# How to show this step of the Riez representation theorem

Tags: measure-theory, riesz-representation-theorem

[image]

I am studying for Bartle's book the elements of integration and lebesgue measure. He leaves this passage as an exercise which is to show that there exists $ g \in L_q $ such that it is worth (8.10) which is: $G(f)=\displaystyle \int fg \ d\mu $ with $G$ linear functional. I have tried to define functions of type $g= \{ sgn f \}|f|^{\alpha}$, but I could not get the result. Can someone give a tip?

Comment: How is the 'proof of the preceding theorem' going? One way is to invoke the Radom-Nykodym differential of the signed measure $A\mapsto G(1_A)$ with respect to $\mu$, where $A\in\mathbf X$ and $1_A$ is its characteristic function.

Comment: @Berci  also could not solve. The author left the two parts of the theorem as an exercise, the previous theorem is the case where $p = 1$ and $q = \infty$. You can better explain this solution path you proposed?